# Where can I see my achievement list, on the PC version of Dragon Age two, purchased through Steam?

Tags: achievements, dragon-age-2

I purchased DA2 through Steam, and I've earned some achievements during play. Where can I see a complete list of the achievements I've earned - they don't show up in my steam account?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Dragon Age 2's achievements can be viewed by logging in to your account at [social.bioware.com](http://social.bioware.com). Make sure whatever e-mail you use for your account matches what you used in game for your EA account.

Once logged in, in the menu on the hover over "My Games", then select "Dragon Age 2". Once that page loads (where you can also see some info about your character(s)), click on "Achievements". This will show you all of the achievements that you've earned.

Comment: You can also view them in-game from the main menu by going to `Extras` -> `Achievements` (if I remember the menu options correctly, I'm at work so can't double-check them atm).

Answer (score 2):

You can see achievements under the Extras menu.  Unfortunately, you have to leave your current game to get to the extras - it's in the initial menu.  So save first.